# Open Excel as read only but avoid the message bar being displayed

Tags: excel, vba

My excel workbook is saved with a password for editing.
When I open the workbook as Read-Only I am getting a pop up in the message bar "This workbook is locked for editing by another user Save as" as shown in below image.
How to avoid the display of this Message when the file is in read-only mode.

[image]

Comment: **How** do you open it as read only? Can you describe the steps? Did you try using a shortcut with the `/r` parameter like `"c:\program files\Microsoft office\office14\excel.exe" /r "c:\temp\book1.xlsx"`?

Comment: Are you opening it using VBA? There is a read-only option in the `Workbooks.Open` method that will not give you that yellow warning box.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening it using VBA, there is a read-only option in the `Workbooks.Open` method that will not give you that yellow warning box.

```
Sub test()
  Dim MyFile As String
  Dim wb As Workbook

  MyFile = "C:\test.xlsx"

  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFile, ReadOnly:=True)

End Sub
```